# how to set JSESSIONID cookie as secure using Spring security 2 and Apache Tomcat 7 setting

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

how to set JSESSIONID cookie as secure using Spring security 2 and Apache Tomcat 7 setting.

have put in the code below in web.xml and it deosn't seem to be working.

```
<cookie-config>
   <secure>true</secure>
</cookie-config>
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <secure>true</secure>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks Istvan Devai. i was checking this again. its actually working.
i was looking at cookie sent from browser and didn't see any flags and thought its not working. but the cookie received does have secure flag. Just learn't that browsers don't send the flags back to server. it uses them internally. Thanks